# How to track only a click on a particular layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

This is `MainActivity.java` and `main.xml`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View p1)
                                {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                        });       
    }   
}
```

`main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#75F575">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#C69817">

        <TextView
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="228.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9.299988dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on 1st (green) and 2nd (yellow) layout - a `Toast` will shows on both layouts. But I need the `Toast` to show up only when I click on 1st layout (`@+id/main_layout`), and NOT TO SHOW UP when I click on the child views (another (yellow) layout and other views).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set attribute **android:clickable="true"** for the second `LinearLayout` (yellow one) with implementing NO listener to it (no changes in java). This will show the toast only when the first `LinearLayout` (green one) is clicked.

P.S. You still can implement listeners to childs of the second `LinearLayout`, e.g. `TextView` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to `setOnClickListener` on each of your childviews with an `onClick` method doing nothing.